# Changing <Video> src based on screen size with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I'm testing on building a site locally on my machine using bootstrap.

I have a `<video>` sort of as the header of the site.

I would like this video to show the full width and height on mobile, and show a cropped/wide version of the video on desktop. I tried using inline media queries in the `<source>` tags, so that the `src` would change but nothing would work.

So I switched gears and used some javascript to change it that way.

So the crazy thing is, it seems my script works. When I look in chrome dev tools, the `src`does in fact change when I resize my browser screen, however, it does not reflect on the site itself, it keeps whatever `src` I set it to in the html, as if it is ignoring my script.

I have tried everything I could think of, and I'm just stuck, not sure how to go about it any further. My code is below:

HTML

```
<video class="col-12" loop muted autoplay >
  <source id="hvid" src="media/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

JS

```
let homeVideo = document.getElementById('hvid')
console.log(homeVideo.src)


function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    homeVideo.src = "media/test.mp4";
  } else {
   homeVideo.src = "media/test-3.mp4";
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
;
console.log(homeVideo.src)
```

***-Edits-***

JS

```
var w = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)");
 var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
 var source = document.getElementById("hvid");


window.addEventListener("resize", function screenres(){
  if (w.matches) {
    vid.pause();
    source.src = "media/test.mp4";
    vid.load();
    vid.play();
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    source.src = "media/test-3.mp4";
    vid.load();
    vid.play();
  };

});
```

HTML

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <video id="vid" class="col-12" loop muted autoplay>
            <source id="hvid" src="media/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should capture the video onload and onerror events to see 1. if it is loading and 2. why not if not

Comment: @AndrewL64 HOLY!!! Thank you so much!! That did it!! I added an eventlistener to when the window resizes and now it changes dynamically whenever I resize the browser. MUCH appreciated, I was racking my brain for hours!!

Comment: @AndrewL64 as I'm experimenting with it more, I'm seeing that it will only work if the window is resized. 

So in the html, I have the full version of the video in the code. So if I load the window to a desktop, it will fire with the default that I have written in the HTML (the full size, and not the cropped I want for desktop)

How can I have it so that the correct video will load to the corresponding screen size?

Comment: @Miguerurso Not really sure what you mean since the current code below and in the jsfiddle does exactly that. If the jsfiddle preview section is resized to say 650px and refreshed, the respective video loads. Same if you resized the code to 750px.

Comment: @AndrewL64 it seems to work in the jsfiddle, but I think by adding the resize event listener in my code, the html first loads the default src I have written in the code (regardless of what size I currently have, so it could be a 300px width or a 1400px width and it will be the same video)  and the video src won't actually change until the window is resized.

Comment: Hmm. Let me check it out.

Comment: @AndrewL64 added my edited code to my original post if you wanted to take a look

Comment: @AndrewL64 it seems like by adding a separate onload event with the same code snippet made it work. Now when I load the window at a low screen size it shows me the corresponding video! Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewL64 Just posted it. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Miguerurso I added a different kind of approach to the answer as well as to the JSFiddle. Check it out. I think the new approach might be a better way to do this. Adding the video element on page load and then toggling it based on screen size prevents the flickering that you can see happened in your JSFiddle.

Comment: @AndrewL64 I see, that works nicely. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get the viewport size, and based on that value, pause the video, change the `src` link, load the new video and play the new video.

But do note that you will need to refresh the page after changing the browser size to see the video change.

If you want the video to change whenever the screen resizes as well as on page refresh, you will first need to move the above JavaScript to a function and run it when a `resize` event is fired. Then, for the page load, you need to remove the video element from your HTML and add it on page load using the [createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) method with the `src` attribute value also added depending on the viewport width.

---

Check this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/6pLua510/46/)** or run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I have described above:

```js
/* JavaScript */

  var w = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)");
  var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
  var source = document.createElement("source");
  source.id = "hvid";
  source.setAttribute("type", "video/mp4");
  vid.appendChild(source);
  
  if (w.matches) {
    vid.pause();
    source.removeAttribute("src");
    source.setAttribute("src", "https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Love-Boat.mp4");
    vid.load();
    vid.play();
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    source.removeAttribute("src");
    source.setAttribute("src", "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4");
    vid.load();
    vid.play();
  }

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
  var w = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)");
  var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
  var source = document.getElementById("hvid");
  
  if (w.matches) {
    vid.pause();
    source.src = "https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Love-Boat.mp4";
    vid.load();
    vid.play();
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    source.src = "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4";
    vid.load();
    vid.play();
  }
});
```

```css
/* CSS */

html, body {margin: 0; padding:0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}.row{display: block !important;}
```

```html
<!-- CDN Links -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- HTML -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <video id="vid" class="col-12" loop muted autoplay></video>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: @Miguerurso I added a different kind of approach to the answer as well as to this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/6pLua510/46/). Check it out. I think the above approach might be a better way to do this.

Comment: @Miguerurso Adding the video element on page load and then toggling it based on screen size prevents the flickering that you can see happened in your JSFiddle.